# nginx `listen` configuration generated by Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator

Tags: ssl, nginx

I use Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator(https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/) to generate a configuration.

My selections are `nginx` and `modern`,the configuration  has a piece of code like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

**Questions:**

1、There are two `listen`s,what is the difference between them?
2、Do I not need to add `server_name` in this `server` block？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. There are two listens, what is the difference between them?**

One is listen IPv4 on port 80 and other is IPv6 on port 80. You only need second one when you want to use IPv6

**2. Do I not need to add server_name in this server block**

Yes you should define `server_name` for the names that your website should be reached on. Also if you only want to allow `www` or `non-www` then you should change below

```
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

to

```
return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
```